# Need help identifying transistor

Tags: transistors, pcb, repair

This board is from a Rhyne UC7067RYE remote receiver for a ceiling fan/light fixture.

[image: Rhyne UC7067RYE board]

I blew the transistor “Q6” (that’s the piece that broke off in pic 3).

[image: Damaged transistor]

[image: Broken piece with markings]

The fan circuit still works fine but the light circuit does not ([manual](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/b0/b013b715-d671-4cbb-9802-f6ef82814c7c.pdf)).

The only markings I could identify were the ones shown in pic 3: **VF08SB RH03**.

I know that the package is a TO-126. The numbers do not follow any transistor marking code standards that I know of (JEDEC/JIS/Pro Electron).

My google searched have not turned up anything that looks promising. I suspect this is a custom number from the OEM and I am not optimistic I will figure out exactly what it is but I was hoping someone might have some tricks for discovering what type of transistor it is so I can at replace it with something similar at least.

Comment: Most probably a TRIAC.

Comment: @winny I suspected that too (seems like it just passes 120 VAC to the light pcb) but I didn’t want to influence anyone’s instincts. What made you think that? if you don’t mind me asking.

Comment: The fact it's in a fan/light AC circuit (and no other larger power devices are visible) hints that it's probably the TRIAC.  The circuit's simple enough that it could be reverse-engineered to determine the correct pin-out of Q6 and it's function.  Chances are good of finding a suitable generic replacement in TO-126.

Comment: Probably something like a 2N6075 sensitive-gate 4A triac would work, but trace the circuit out to make sure that makes sense and see what might have killed it (perhaps a failed MOV)

Comment: What @rdtsc said, and probably 8A 300 V rating given the name.

Comment: I killed it while measuring the supply to the light pcb. Tried to be lazy and probe the molex connector with both probes in one hand. Heard it pop. That’s what I get for taking a “shortcut”....